# How to get Mouse Out effect in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mousehover

I have created a transition effect on a `div`. I have written the following code and its working fine, when I `hover` on the `div`, the color smoothly changes, but when I remove the mouse the color backs to its original state abruptly.

I want to know the method of changing the color slowly on `Mouse out` Event as well.

Kindly check my code and guide me.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="skills" class="navText" >Work -Experience</li>
        <li id="web" class="navText">Skills </li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav ul #skills 
{
    position:absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border:6px solid;
    border-color:white;
    border-radius: 150px;
    line-height:150px;
    font-size: 15px;

    #background-color: EA7079;
    background-color:   #1A1A1A;
    color: white;

    left:370px;     
}           

nav ul #skills:hover
{
    position:absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border:6px solid;
    border-color:   #DCDEE0;
    border-radius: 150px;
    line-height:150px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: EA7079;
    color: white;

    left:370px;

    /*  CSS3 */
   -webkit-transition: all 1000ms ;
   -moz-transition: all 1000ms ;
   -ms-transition: all 1000ms ;
   -o-transition: all 1000ms ;
   transition: all 1000ms ;     
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get this hover effect with just CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460149/how-to-get-this-hover-effect-with-just-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you only have transition on the non-hovered element, according to [CSS-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/)

```
av ul #skills 
{
    position:absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border:6px solid;
    border-color:white;
    border-radius: 150px;
    line-height:150px;
    font-size: 15px;

    #background-color: EA7079;
    background-color:   #1A1A1A;
    color: white;

    left:370px;
    /*  CSS3 */
-webkit-transition: all 1000ms ;
-moz-transition: all 1000ms ;
-ms-transition: all 1000ms ;
-o-transition: all 1000ms ;
transition: all 1000ms ;    


    }   


nav ul #skills:hover
{
    position:absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border:6px solid;
    border-color:   #DCDEE0;
    border-radius: 150px;
    line-height:150px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: EA7079;
    color: white;

    left:370px;


}
```

Comment: This is how I thought it would work. But when I look at the code I just posted, it causes a lot of flickering, at least in chrome. I'm taking a look to see if it might be because I'm specifying 'all'.

Comment: At CSS tricks, I notice they only apply the transition to the non-hovered element, but I'm still looking into how that works out with your example.

Answer (score 4):

It is changing back suddenly because you have the transitions in the :hover rule. The transitions only works when the mouse is over the element.
Do it like this instead:

```
nav ul #skills 
{
    position:absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border:6px solid;
    border-color:white;
    border-radius: 150px;
    line-height:150px;
    font-size: 15px;
    #background-color: EA7079;
    background-color:   #1A1A1A;
    color: white;
    left:370px;
    /*  CSS3 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1000ms ;
    -moz-transition: all 1000ms ;
    -ms-transition: all 1000ms ;
    -o-transition: all 1000ms ;
    transition: all 1000ms ;
        } 
nav ul #skills:hover
{
    position:absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border:6px solid;    
    border-color:   #DCDEE0;
    border-radius: 150px;
    line-height:150px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: EA7079;
    color: white;
    left:370px;
    }
```

See? The transitions are applied only when the mouse is over the element because it is in the :hover rule. Thus, it cannot fade back out after the mouse leaves because the transitions are no longer applied. If the transitions are applied to the elements style, it will fade in and out every time the mouse moves over it.
[Here is a JSFiddle to show what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/MisterHappy/Kyvux/).
Hope this helps!